# .htaccess redirect site X to site Y without loosing URI

Tags: redirection, htaccess

I tried to figure out how to redirect 401.shtml to index.php.

It works like this:

```
Redirect /401.shtml /index.php
```

But if there is a URI then it should redirect to the URI instead of index.php.

e.g. if it is like:

```
https://www.old-domain.de/login
```

then it does redirect to

```
https://www.new-domain.de/401.shtml
```

which currently then redirects to

```
https://www.new-domain.de/index.php
```

But I need it to redirect to:

```
https://www.new-domain.de/login
```

How can I make it to keep the URI, is this even possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "[_URI_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier)"? Which part of `scheme://authority/path?query#fragment`? The whole thing is the URI. Can you give an example?

Comment: @Attie, I added an example

Comment: Just looking at your question title alone, this sounds perfectly reasonable (pretty much a standard _wildcard_ redirect). However, the rest of your question doesn't seem to make sense? Why are you _redirecting_ from `/401.shtml` to `/index.php`? Why is `/login` _redirected_ to `/401.shtml` on the new domain? What is doing that? (That sounds like the user has failed some kind of authentication? - but why the redirect? - and why the authentication?) Apache `.htaccess` redirection questions are better suited to [Webmasters SE](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @MrWhite, yes good question. I want to redirect to index.php because sometimes 401.shtml is showing in the URL even though I am successfully authenticated and then I get a 404 site, .